# ICC not activated

Tags: c++, c, smartcard, apdu

I am currently trying to hack my way into Smart Cards but I am now stuck at reading anything useful from the Card. I am trying to send a SELECT FILE Command (`0x6F, 0xB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,    0x00, 0xa4, 0x04, 0x0c, 0x06, 0xd2, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02`) to my Card (after PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn, which returns the correct ATR) with the PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock Command.

But my response has the `bmICCStatus` Flag set to `0x40` which indicates the "ICC is present and inactive (not activated or shut down by hardware error)" but I am not quite sure what to do with that information. How am I supposed to activate the Card? I thought powering it was all there was to it.

It is very much possible that I am just blind and it is written in the Specification but I was not able to find it and my Google Searches lead me to exactly 1 SO Question, which didn't really corrolate with my problem.

I am using libusb 1.0 and C, but I don't think that this is relevant to the question.

Edit:

I've added an code example, but you have to select your device
for yourself, if you want to run it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TIMEOUT 1000

void print_bytes(unsigned char * arr, int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("%0.2x ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    /* I have some logic which is not included to find the apropriate sc-reader. */
    /* Please use libusb_get_device_list() or similar to select your device. */
    libusb_device * egk_sc_reader = NULL;

    libusb_device_handle * handle = NULL;
    int k = libusb_open(egk_sc_reader, &handle);

    int transferred = 0;

    libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);

    unsigned char cmd_pwr_on[] = {
        0x62,   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   0x00, 0x00
    };

    unsigned char cmd_select_file[] = {
        // CMD (1), LEN (4), Slot (1), Seq (1), Block Wait Time (1), Level Parameter (2), abData (LEN)
        0x6F, 0xB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa4, 0x04, 0x0c, 0x06, 0xd2, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02
    };

    int buf_in_len = 128;
    unsigned char buf_in[buf_in_len];
    memset(buf_in, 0, buf_in_len);

    // Write power on
    libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, 0x05, cmd_pwr_on, sizeof(cmd_pwr_on), &transferred, TIMEOUT);

    // read atr
    libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, 0x86, buf_in, buf_in_len, &transferred, TIMEOUT);

    print_bytes(buf_in, buf_in_len);
    memset(buf_in, 0, 128);

    // Write select command
    libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, 0x05, cmd_select_file, sizeof(cmd_select_file), &transferred, TIMEOUT);

    // read answer
    libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, 0x86, buf_in, buf_in_len, &transferred, TIMEOUT);

    print_bytes(buf_in, buf_in_len);

    libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
    libusb_close(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

This Code example tries to mimic my actual code. It is not exactly the same but the result matches my problem As the stdout is:

```
80 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 3b d3 96 ff 81 b1 fe 45 1f 07 80 81 05 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
80 00 00 00 00 00 01 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The Reader I am using is the `USB SMARTCARD READER` from `WD Plus GmbH` and the Smart Card is the `EGK (Elektronische Gesundheitskarte) (en: Electronic Healtcare Card)` from the `Bahn BKK`. The Card supports T=0 and T=1 (Gematik Specification: https://fachportal.gematik.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachportal/files/Spezifikationen/Basis-Rollout/Elektronische_Gesundheitskarte/gemLF_Impl_eGK_V160.pdf)

Just sending the APDU returns me an 'Index of not supported / incorrect message parameter' Error. Which makes sense, when I think about it.

Thanks in advance
Cediwelli

Comment: I disagree with regards to the reproducible code sample; if you are starting it is easy to overlook something. Furthermore, you haven't specified the (Gemalto or is it ACS?) reader or even smart card you are trying to connect to. Please add this information. Have you tried just sending the APDU itself (`0x00, 0xa4, 0x04, 0x0c, 0x06, 0xd2, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02`)?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Hey, thank you for your answer! I've added a code example which reproduces my problem. Just sending the APDU returns me an 'Index of not supported / incorrect message parameter' Error from the Reader. Hardware Specifications are below the code example.

Comment: don't tag both C and C++. They're different languages

Comment: @phuclv This is not a programming question or a question specific to any language. I chose C/C++ because I believe these are the languages that are familiar to people that are well versed with the CCID Specification. But thank you for your comment!

Comment: I would not even attempt to address the card via the USB interface, since addressing cards is complicated enough without to heap on it one of the most universal (i. e. complicated) interface families. Try to get hold of the appropriate PCSC library for your operating system.

Comment: @guidot Hey, thank you for your comment! You seem versed in the field of SmartCards. I appreciate your idea and I will probably use a pcsc library but do you have an idea why the SC Reader might respond with `"ICC is present and inactive (not activated or shut down by hardware error)"`?

Comment: @Cediwelli: that sounds, as if the card was not properly powered on, i.e. got no reset signal. This should be easy to verify, since it triggers the card to send its ATR.

Comment: @guidot Well the problem is that I actually send the PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn and I even get the correct ATR (see first paragraph of question) I tried sending the Signal multiple times even and I still get the same "present and Inactive" status. This is some weird behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ATR your card is T=1 only https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/parse?ATR=3BD396FF81B1FE451F078081052D

I don't know the reader you use. If the reader works in TPDU and not APDU it is more complex than just sending the APDU. You have to implement T=1 in your code.

I guess the missing CCID command is PC_to_RDR_SetParameters to configure the reader with the correct parameters.

I would really suggest to use already existing software. Like my CCID driver https://ccid.apdu.fr/ for Unix.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I already found a lot of your stuff. (I actually thought about writing you an email for help but I didn't want to waste your time '^^). A few weeks after this post, I gave up and used your library. It worked really well and I can only recommend it. The thing is, I mainly want(ed) to do this stuff to learn it. Probably I'll try it at some point in the future again, but in the meantime I'll use your library and study it. Cheers

Comment: Then you could mark my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: If you would be so kind and add to the answer a more detailed view on the original question ("How am I supposed to activate the Card? I thought powering it was all there was to it.") and how that correlates to sending the data in the different protocols, I would very happily accept your answer as the correct one. I am now confused as the card-reader definitly was able to retrieve the ATR with the powerOn command via APDU without me even knowing about TPDU.